# Could not find generator 'devise:install' unless using sudo rails generate devise:install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a rails app that I am trying to install devise on.

I use the command 
`rails generate devise:install`
but it fails, giving this message:

`Could not find generator 'devise:install'. Maybe you meant 'ckeditor:install', 'assets' or 'comment'`

however if I use `sudo rails generate devise:install` it works.

I do not want to generate devise:install as root however.

I have done `chmod a+x` on the directory.

I also recently changed macbooks and imported my ssh key from the previous macbook, but I added the key with ssh-add. Not sure if this is the problem.

this is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
gem 'thin'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'devise', '3.5.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'bootstrap_form'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem "rmagick", :require => 'RMagick'
gem 'ckeditor'
gem 'acts_as_commentable'
gem 'addressable'
gem 'vimeo'
gem 'underscore-rails'
gem 'gmaps4rails'
gem 'geocoder'
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'pry'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'

end

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I managed to solve this by deleting my Gemfile.lock, doing `bundle install` again and then stopping spring with `spring stop` I could then call the generator without root privileges

Comment: I did not need to delete the Gemfile.lock. Just spring stop was enough.

Answer (score -1):

It's kind of weird, but I solve the problem restarting my mac